# MediaElement.js and FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mediaelement.js

I have this simple code:

HTML

```
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

   <script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
   <link href="build/mediaelementplayer.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <video id="video-player" preload="preload" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source type="video/youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7o7R5BgWDY" />
   </video>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
   $('video').mediaelementplayer();
});
```

I have this uploaded on my server together with the files from http://mediaelementjs.com/ in the build directory. All the mediaelement files are inside the build directory, while index and the js file is in root.

In Chrome this runs without any problems, same goes in explorer/Edge. But FireFox won't run it. The player with all the controlls loads but the video doesn't play and pressing the play button does nothing either. Adobe Flash is enabled in firefox aswell while trying this.

Made the same example in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zE26G/27/
Here the video in the jsfiddle instead runs in FireFox, but not in Chrome/IE..

Firebug is giving these warnings in both the examples:

> "Specified "type" attribute of "video/youtube" is not supported. Load
>   of media resource https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7o7R5BgWDY failed."
>
> "All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused."

While the console in Chrome doesn't give any errors.

This is very odd to me. Anyone who have a clue on whats going on here?

Comment: I Had two friends try the same example on a server with FireFox, apparently it is working for them. But i still can't get the video to load on my end. Tried old/new FireFox versions and updated the flash player.. Still nothing

Comment: Seems to work if i completely remove flash from my computer, then firefox will use html5 to play the videos instead. Is there a way to force browsers to play videos with html5 instead of flash? And secondly use flash if html5 isn't supported

Answer (score 0):

This was already reported here: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1684

I got similar issue and was fixed with updating library to the latest version.